# Kotlinx deserialization does not include properties from abstract class when using "JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer"

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

Lets say there is abstract class *BaseClass* ...

```
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable(with = PolymorphicSerializer::class)
abstract class BaseClass {
    @SerialName("bid")
    var baseId: String? = null
 }
```

... class *ExtendedClass* that extends it ...

```
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
class ExtendedClass
    (@SerialName("eid")
     var newId: String? = null
) : BaseClass()
```

... and *PolymorphicSerializer*

```
import kotlinx.serialization.DeserializationStrategy
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonElement

object PolymorphicSerializer  : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<BaseClass>(BaseClass::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<out BaseClass> {
        return ExtendedClass.serializer()
    }
}
```

*PolymorphicSerializer* is used because JSON can be deserialized as different classes that extend *BaseClass* based on some property (for sake of simplicity I just used *ExtendedClass.serializer()* )

Now, if we try to deserialize generic JSON to *ExtendedClass* ...

```
class DeserializationTest {
    @Test
    fun deserialization_isCorrect() {
        val extendedClass = Json {
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        }.decodeFromString<BaseClass>("""{"bid":"bid","eid":"eid"}""")

        assertEquals("bid", extendedClass.baseId)
    }
}
```

... test fails

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :bid
Actual   :null
```

If I try to serialize *ExtendedClass* ...

```
val extendedClass = ExtendedClass()
extendedClass.baseId = "bid"
extendedClass.newId = "eid"

val encodedJson = Json {
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
}.encodeToString(extendedClass)
```

I can see *encodedJson* is *{"eid":"eid"}* but if I remove *JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer* this works fine (replace *@Serializable(with = PolymorphicSerializer::class)* with *@Serializable* ), *encodedJson* is *{"bid":"bid","eid":"eid"}*

So, for some reason *JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer* does not take into account properties from super class.

Anyone knows why is that so?

Comment: Did you find solution? Im thinking of including two properties with the same value, one acting as the selecer - as it's seemingly removed

Comment: @MikkelT there is an issue on Github and a workaround is mentioned there: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1433

Unfortunately, still no nice solution for the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You are overriding the generated serializer for `BaseClass` by providing your *custom* `PolymorphicSerializer`:

```
@Serializable(with = PolymorphicSerializer::class)
abstract class BaseClass { ... }
```

You have effectively erased the serializer for `BaseClass`. (In fact, I'm surprised this doesn't throw some type of error/failing deserialization.)

Instead, remove `@Serializable`, and wherever you need to deserialize JSON which does not contain a class discriminator, pass your custom `PolymorphicSerializer` as the parameter to `decodeFromString`.

P.s. I would also recommend to name it differently. `PolymorphicSerializer` is an actual serializer in kotlinx.serialization which threw me off. ;)

Comment: Hi Steven. Sorry about naming, it was just dummy name, unfortunately a bad one.

Regarding your solution, I just tried it, but it does not work, baseId is still null after deserialization.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. Moreover, sometimes you need to declare the custom `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer` in the base class, for example when you need it to serialize a polymorphic `List< BaseClass >` (from the example above). AFAIK there is no way to implement a custom List serializer that works with polymorphic collections.

Comment: @fast3r Then you need to create a `ListSerializer` and pass your custom serializer as the parameter.